# How do I pass a C++ callback to a C library function?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, casting

I'm developing my code using C++ and want to use MPFIT nonlinear curve fitting library, which is developed in C but allows to compile in C++.

For example I have a class named "myClass", and this class has a function myClass::Execute()

I include "mpfit.h" to myClass.h file. And try to call a function called mpfit from Execute().

```
int status = mpfit(ErrorFunction, num1, num2, xsub_1D, 0, 0, (void *) &variables, &result);
```

The problem is ErrorFunction is a function of myClass. So compiler gives error when I try to use this. I tried to carry the ErrorFunction out of the class object, but this time I take the error given below:

Error when the ErrorFunction is outside of the class:

> Error 4   error C2664: 'mpfit' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int
>   (__cdecl *)(int,int,double *,double,double *,void *)' to
>   'mp_func'

Error when the ErrorFunction is inside the class:

```
Error   3   error C3867: 'myClass::ErrorFunction': function call missing argument list; use '&myClass::ErrorFunction' to
```

Definition of error function:

```
int ErrorFunction(int dummy1, int dummy2, double* xsub, double *diff, double **dvec, void *vars)
```

How can I call this function and parse it into mpfit, which is a C function?

`mp_func` is defined as:

```
/* Enforce type of fitting function */
typedef int (*mp_func)(int m, /* Number of functions (elts of fvec) */
               int n, /* Number of variables (elts of x) */
               double *x,      /* I - Parameters */
               double *fvec,   /* O - function values */
               double **dvec,  /* O - function derivatives (optional)*/
               void *private_data); /* I/O - function private data*/
```

Comment: As a side issue, be careful not to throw any uncaught exceptions in your C++ callback function. Depending on architecture, you might find they will not go through the C call stack without seg faulting or something similiar.

Comment: @Component10: and even if they did make it through the C call stack, there's a reasonable chance that the C code will have leaked memory as a consequence of the exception. So it's no great advantage if they do make it out without a segfault, although it might help a little with debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your calling conventions match.  C libraries use the C calling convention, or cdecl (__cdecl).  If you're using the mp_func typedef within C++, it could be defaulting to the compiler's standard calling convention, or stdcall (__stdcall).  Either make a new typedef or change it to the following:

```
typedef int __cdecl (*mp_func)(int m, /* Number of functions (elts of fvec) */
               int n, /* Number of variables (elts of x) */
               double *x,      /* I - Parameters */
               double *fvec,   /* O - function values */
               double **dvec,  /* O - function derivatives (optional)*/
               void *private_data); /* I/O - function private data*/
```

And when you declare ErrorFunction, also declare it as __cdecl:

```
int __cdecl ErrorFunction(int, int, double*, double *, double **, void *);
```

If the compiler still complains when calling the mpfit function, you can try casting your function pointer to the mp_func typedef with cdecl:

```
int status = mpfit((mp_func)ErrorFunction, num1, num2, xsub_1D, 0, 0, (void *) &variables, &result);
```

Comment: thank you. I used mpfit((mp_func)ErrorFunction.....) while defining ErrorFunction out of the class. It works.

Comment: Good to hear.  Also, when passing callback functions around they can only be class members if they are also defined as static.

Answer (score 3):

Given the definitions of `mpfit()` and `mp_func` that you have shown, you would need to use the `private_data` parameter of `mp_func` to pass your class's `this` pointer around.  You are currently using that parameter to pass your `variables` item around instead.  Make `variables` be a member of your class (if it is not already) and then pass `this` to `mpfit()` instead:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    TheDataType variables;
    static int ErrorFunction(int m, int n, double *x, double *fvec, double **dvec, MyClass *pThis);
public:
    void DoIt();
};

void MyClass::DoIt()
{
    // ...
    int status = mpfit((mp_func)&ErrorFunction, num1, num2, xsub_1D, 0, 0, this, &result); 
    // ...
}

int MyClass::ErrorFunction(int m, int n, double* x, double *fvec, double **dvec, MyClass *pThis)
{
    // use pThis->variables as needed ...
}
```

Or:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    static int MPFitErrorFunction(int m, int n, double *x, double *fvec, double **dvec, MyClass *pThis);
    int MyErrorFunction(int m, int n, double *x, double *fvec, double **dvec);
public:
    void DoIt();
};

void MyClass::DoIt()
{
    // ...
    int status = mpfit((mp_func)&MPFitErrorFunction, num1, num2, xsub_1D, 0, 0, this, &result); 
    // ...
}

int MyClass::MPFitErrorFunction(int m, int n, double* x, double *fvec, double **dvec, MyClass *pThis)
{
    return pThis->MyErrorFunction(m, n, x, fvec, dvec);
} 

int MyClass::MyErrorFunction(int m, int n, double* x, double *fvec, double **dvec)
{
    // use this->variables as needed ...
}
```

Comment: You should *not* be casting `&MPFitErrorFunction` to `mp_func` -- you should instead declare it with the proper signature, i.e. the last parameter should be `void*` instead of `MyClass*`.  Not only does the cast hide potential errors, it's technically Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I do the type-cast because a `void*` pointer and a `MyClass*` pointer are the same in memory, so it just avoids the use of a local variable and a type-cast inside the function: `int MyClass::ErrorFunction(int m, int n, double* x, double *fvec, double **dvec, void *private_data) 
{ 
MyClass *pThis = (MyClass*) private_data; // use pThis->variables as needed ... 
}`

Comment: @Remy: but the cast conceals errors. The questioner originally had the wrong signature in the function (including a `double` which should have been `double*`). You want to take advantage of something that just so happens to work on your implementation (passing a parameter as `void*` but receiving it as `MyClass*`), so you think the cast is harmless. But passing a parameter as `double*` and receiving it as `double` doesn't work on any implementation, so hiding the error for it just leads to trouble. And neither of them is guaranteed to work, albeit yours does work approximately everywhere.

Comment: It's similar to the classic error of writing `const_cast<T*>(t)`, and thinking "all that does is remove const", and carefully writing your code to ensure that `t` really points to a mutable object. All very well, but if you accidentally use a `t` that points to a *volatile* mutable object, `const_cast` removes the volatile too, that you forgot to think about and you have UB. Your cast has disabled one type check that you're aware of and accounted for, but also disabled other type checks that would catch bugs (such as if the rest of the signature or the calling convention didn't match).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like instead of:

```
int ErrorFunction(int dummy1, int dummy2, double* xsub, double diff, double *dvec, void *vars)
```

it should be:

```
int ErrorFunction(int dummy1, int dummy2, double* xsub, double *diff, double **dvec, void *vars)
```

to match your

```
typedef int (*mp_func)(int m, /* Number of functions (elts of fvec) */
               int n, /* Number of variables (elts of x) */
               double *x,      /* I - Parameters */
               double *fvec,   /* O - function values */
               double **dvec,  /* O - function derivatives (optional)*/
               void *private_data); /* I/O - function private data*/
```

Comment: I made the change but it didn't work out. Same error. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Emre: you got the same error? You changed the signature of `ErrorFunction` to take a `double*` as the 4th parameter and `double**` as the 5th parameter, and you still got the error "cannot convert from `'int (__cdecl *)(int,int,double *,double,double *,void *)'`?

Answer (score 1):

Your callback must be declared `extern "C"` for this to work.

**Edit**: I see people are having hard time grasping this fact. The standard says (7.5/1):

> Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types
>   even if they are otherwise identical.

Comment: `extern "C"` is only needed to turn off C++ name mangling so that C code can call C++ code. Since the call is through a function pointer and doesn't require assistance from the linker to connect caller and callee, `extern "C"` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ferruccio: There's a belief that language linkage equals name mangling. It is wrong. The standard plainly states that language linkage is the part of the **type**. Two otherwise identical functions with different language linkage have **different types**. G++ treats them as identical, but that's G++'s own problem. The [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2316) is open in GCC bugzilla since 2001 (that's for 11 years).

Comment: Yes, the type includes the function signature and the calling convention, which defaults to `__cdecl` in both C & C++ programs. I'm not saying that name mangling is all there is to linkage. What I'm saying is that, since the calling conventions already match and there is no need for the linker to resolve the name of the function, the `extern "C"` declaration is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ferruccio Of course it is necessary. You are passing a function pointer as an argument to a function. The type of the argument must match the type of the formal parameter, or the compiler will complain. The formal parameter has C linkage because the function itself has C linkage. Therefore your function pointer must be of C linkage. Note that **the type includes the language linkage**, not just the signature and the calling convention.

Comment: The language linkage doesn't matter in this case because you're passing around a memory address and not a symbol name.  The calling convention, however, does matter.

Comment: @syplex: We in C++ assign **types** to stuff we pass around and stick to these types. A pointer to `char` is a different type from a pointer to `int`. You don't mix them, though both are just memory addresses deep down. In the same fashion, a pointer to C-function is a different type from a pointer to a C++-function. That's what the standard says.

Comment: The type of the formal parameter is "pointer to function" not "pointer to extern C function". Is a C++ compiler allowed to assume that because the function being called is extern "C" then any function pointers passed into it are also extern "C"? I really don't know what the standard says on this. It's always worked fine for me without the extern "C" declaration (of course, that really doesn't mean anything).

Comment: @Ferruccio: Language linkage of any formal parameter is by default the same as that of the function itself. 7.5/4 says "In a linkage specification, the specified language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage declared within the linkage-specification." Formal parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard idiom for C++ - to - C, using the pimpl idiom:

foo_c.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
//forward declaration.  clients of foo_c.h should only hold pointers to Foo_c
typedef struct Foo_c Foo_c;

int someMethod(Foo_c* foo);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

foo_c.cpp:

```
#include <foo.h>
struct Foo_c {
       Foo foo;
}
int someMethod(Foo_c* foo) { 
     try {
         foo->foo.someMethod();
         return 0; //no error
     }
     catch(...) {
         return 1; //error
     }
}
```

(Edited for extern "C"'s per below answer.)

Comment: You don't need the `Foo_c` struct, you could just pass the `Foo` pointer around instead.  But either way, this idiom only works if the C library allows you to specify a user-defined value in the first place.  It looks like `mpfit()` may allow that, but many C libraries do not.